# Python MQTT callbacks not called

Tags: python, mqtt, python-multithreading

I'm working on a mqtt-subscriber which forwards the messages to a beanstalk-tube or api-endpoint. I came up with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pymysql.cursors
import sys
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from threading import Thread


class Process(Thread):
    def __init__(self, sid=None, host=None, username=None, password=None, topic=None, topic_qos=None, destination_type=None, destination=None):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sid = sid
        self.host = host
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.topic = topic
        self.topic_qos = topic_qos
        self.destination_type = destination_type
        self.destination = destination
        self.client = None

    def on_connect(self, client, obj, flags, rc):
        print("connected")
        self.client.subscribe(self.topic, qos=self.topic_qos)
        self.client.loop_forever()

    def on_message(self, client, obj, msg):
        print(str(msg.payload))

    def run(self):
        self.client = mqtt.Client(str(self.sid) + "_subscriber")
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.client.username_pw_set(self.username, self.password)
        self.client.connect(self.host, 1883, 60)


def main(argv):
    db_connection = pymysql.connect(host=argv[0],
                                    user=argv[1],
                                    password=argv[2],
                                    db=argv[3],
                                    charset='utf8mb4',
                                    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    processes = []
    try:
        with db_connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT `id`,`topic`,`topic_qos`,`target_type`,`target` FROM mqtt_subscriptions;")
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            for subscription in result:
                process = Process(subscription['id'], argv[4], argv[5], argv[6], subscription['topic'],
                                         subscription['topic_qos'], subscription['target_type'],
                                         subscription['target'])
                process.start()
                processes.append(process)
    finally:
        db_connection.close()
        while True:
            #print("check for new imports")
            time.sleep(4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The problem is that the methods in the class Process aren't triggered. This could be due to the fact that I'm using OOP and all the examples are not. But this must be possible right?

Would love to hear your ideas or suggestions.

Gino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the call to `self.client.loop_forever()` out of the `on_connect()` callback and put it immediately after the call to `self.client.connect(self.host, 1883, 60)`

Callbacks should return quickly, what you've done is make it so the callback never returns.